# How to preload edit form in bootstrap modal window?

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a table with each row having edit button. On click of edit button I am able to open a nifty modal bootstrap window. I have two questions as below

1. What is the best way to preload the values in the form opening in modal window?
   One which I have applied is creating unique id for `<td>` like as below

   ```html
       <tr>    
         <td id="amt<?php echo $c->id; ?>" data-amount="<?php echo $c->amount; ?>">$<?php echo $c->amount; ?></td>
           <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm md-trigger editwin" data-id="<?php echo $c->id; ?>" data-modal="form-edit-window">Edit</a>
       </tr>
   ```

   So I have four rows with amount `<td>` identified as "amt1" ,"amt2".."amt4"
   Now in js I am reading and setting the values. But, I believe it's a old way to do it. I tried giving amt column "data-amount" attribute but it doesn't work for me. It shows value- undefined !. But data-id I can read in JavaScript... I am confused why so?

   Can someone please advice what is best way I can implement this.
2. I have a hidden form field define as `Former->hidden("id")->value($id)`. When the data is posted I am not able to receive the form hidden value in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose exampleModal is the id of opening modal , on opening it "show.bs.modal" event will fire.

Put data-userid = 5 in the edit button.  So that $(event.relatedTarger).data("userid") will get that id and you can put that id in the modal hidden field. All you need to make a form in that modal. Which will post form to backend with that hidden userid.

See example from Getbootstrap.com

```
 $( '#exampleModal' ).on
   ('show.bs.modal' , function
   (event) {
   var button =
   $(event.relatedTarget) //
   Button that triggered the
   modal
  var recipient = button.data
  ('whatever' ) // Extract info
  from data-* attributes
  $("#hiddeninputfield").val(recipient);
      })
```

Comment: nifty modal doesn't support `relatedTarget` and also doesn't support `show.bs.modal` should read the question again.